# (SQL) Add date entry and date_update columns to existing SQL table

Tags: sql, date, sqlalchemy, sql-update, mysql-python

so I have a SQL table

```
id    Name
1     Robert
2     Emily
```

How do I add a column that automatically populates the date of entry and then a second column that populates the date_updated anytime a record is updated (id 2, Emily was "updated" to Emily Ryan below), but defaults to the date_entry if the date has not been updated?:

```
id    Name         date_entry     date_updated
1     Robert       '2020-07-08'   '2020-07-08'
2     Emily Ryan   '2020-07-08'   '2020-07-09'
```

Answer (score 0):

The inserted day is easily solved using a default value for the colum. When new data is inserted. It will get populated with the current date if you do not specify a value for it.

For the update date you will need to create a trigger.

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD COLUMN date_entry DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE();
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD COLUMN date_updated DATE;

CREATE TRIGGER YourTable.update_date_updated  
BEFORE UPDATE ON YourTable 
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    SET new.date_updated = CURRENT_DATE();
END
```